# Get content of DOM element without the parent by using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here are some simple examples what I am trying to do:

```
$("<li>Foo</li>")
    => "Foo"
$("<li><span>Foo</span></li>")
    => <span>Foo</span>
$('<li class="foo"><div>Foo</div><div>Bar</div></li>')
    => <div>Foo</div><div>Bar</div>
```

I know of the jQuery `get()` method, but this just gives me the `<li>` elments, too. A `.children().get()` does not work (at least in the first case). Is there a simple way to achieve that (with built in jQuery methods)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$("<li>Foo</li>").html()
$("<li><span>Foo</span></li>").html()
$('<li class="foo"><div>Foo</div><div>Bar</div></li>').html()
```

Answer (score 2):

To get the children of a node including text nodes, use the `contents()` method instead of `children()`.

Comment: +1 - I think this is the generalized solution the OP is looking for.

Comment: Even if it works now with the html() method, I still ask myself how the contents() exactly works. I also tried that method before, but when I do a $('<li>Foo</li>').contents().get() I still don't get the results of my example.